# Problem printing array and indexes - console logs all, output only prints the last one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to print an array with indexes on the page. Console logs all indexes, but only last one prints out. In the code like this:

```
<body>
  <p id="answer"></p>
<script>
  let array = [11, 22, 33, 44];
  for (let value of array) {
    results = array.indexOf(value) + ':' + value;
    console.log(results);
      }
   document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=results
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: All the JS code is executed before the browser gets time to re-render the page. At that time `innerHTML` has been set to the last value.

Comment: Well on each step you're overwriting the value of `results`. When the loop ends, you're left with the last value only. In the `console`, you should see all the indexes . However, your `p` will display the last value only.

Comment: What are you expecting? after the loop is finished executing the `results` variable will hold the last result of the loop and which will be printed in `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the part inside of the loop to `innerHTML`.

```js
let array = [11, 22, 33, 44],
    result;

for (let value of array) {
    results = array.indexOf(value) + ':' + value;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += results + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<p id="answer"></p>
```

A better version, could be to collect the wanted information and join a new string from the results.

```js
let array = [11, 22, 33, 44];

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = array
    .map((v, i) => [i, v].join(':'))
    .join('<br>');
```

```html
<p id="answer"></p>
```